# manifestPlaceHolders not replacing value

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to replace a value in my AndroidManifest.xml:

I have a debug Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="${mapsApiKey}" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is just a partial that the manifest merge merges with the entire Application.

In my gradle build script:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        manifestPlaceholders = [debugMapsApiKey: "${DEBUG_MAPS_API_KEY}"]
    }
}
```

DEBUG_MAPS_API_KEY is defined in my gradle.properties file.  However I do not see the substitution taking place.

What gives?

Answer (score 4):

You declared at script

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled false
    manifestPlaceholders = [debugMapsApiKey: "${DEBUG_MAPS_API_KEY}"]
}
```

placeholder as **debugMapsApiKey**, but at Manifest used another name **mapsApiKey**

> android:value="${mapsApiKey}"